# Gmaps4rails sidebar disappears when dynamically updating map

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails, sidebar

I'm using a slider to dynamically update the Gmaps4rails google map, however whenever I move the slider and the markers get updated by the replaceMarkers function the sidebar disappears and the only way I can get a list of markers to load again is by refreshing the page.  Does anyone know any way to fix this issue?

Comment: file a feature request in the wiki. Sidebar was supported with minimum features, I could do better in 2.0

Comment: thanks, I looked at the wiki page on github but couldn't find a feature request so I submitted it as an issue.